# What Versioning can do in XCode?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, version, versioning

I saw the `Versioning` config in `Build Settings` of my XCode 4.0.2 and have no idea of what I can do with it. Obvious, this is about version, but what this mean at all?

Anyone know a good text about it?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with general software versioning. I just answer the same question. Look at [Develop Version Numbering for an Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847726/develop-version-numbering-for-an-application/6847819#6847819)